# Chrome v90 flex scroll bug

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

Some of our users reported not being able to scroll on our site anymore. After debugging we found that this was happening for users who are on [Chrome v90](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-chrome-90/). Chrome v89 seems to work fine.

This seems to be caused by a pretty specific combination of css, see the minimal example below. You can also find a working example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kvyrs0pb/).

```css
div {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

#container {
  flex: 1;
  max-height: 100%;
}

#root {
  flex: 1;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

#scrollview {
    display: flex;
    overflow: scroll;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}

#big {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2000px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#FA0050, #000000);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="root">
    <div id="scrollview">
      <div id="big">
        Scroll me!<br><br>
        I can scroll on chrome v89<br>
        I cannot scroll on chrome v90
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the above snippet, scrolling works (Windows & MacOS):

- Version 89.0.4389.114 (Official Build) (x86_64)

In the above snippet, scrolling does not work (Windows & MacOS):

- Version 90.0.4430.72 (Official Build) (x86_64)

Fixing the issue with css is relatively straightforward, however I am interested in finding out why the scrolling no longer works on v90. What exactly has Chrome changed that stops it from working? Did they change something intentionally or is this a bug?

Comment: What is there to scroll? You've got `2000px` worth of space and content that fits in three lines worth of regular sized text (which in most use scenarios is less than 100 pixels tall). Do you just want a scroll bar?

Comment: The `2000px` empty space with a nice gradient background is what should be scrollable so that you can go all the way to the end of the gradient. I want to know why this scrolls on chrome v89 and below, and no longer on v90.

Comment: Testing your markup and style it looks to have something to do with how flex containers calculate their height, where evidently Chrome 90 has changed something. Interesting.

Comment: Reproducible on Chrome 90.0.4430.72 - MacOs 10.15.7. [Screen Recording](https://streamable.com/83uw0o)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like column and row now create some sort of inline box to define it's width. row has the same with overflow-x. you can find the changes of chrome here: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-90/. as u can see in the images below that it makes a div around it's content.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Good find! However if I remove `flex: 1` from the #root element, the scroll works again but the smaller 'inline' box is still there. So I'm not sure if it has something to do with it.

Comment: hmmm thats weird. but i think this is deffenitly a bug and should be reported :)

Answer (score 0):

change

> flex:1;

to

> flex: 1 1 auto;

Comment: "*Fixing the issue with css is relatively straightforward, however I am interested in finding out why the scrolling no longer works on v90.*' -- OP already knows how to fix this, he's looking for an explanation which your question does not provide. Please take a look at [answer].